# WSS to WS in traefik fails with phantombot image

Tags: traefik

I am trying to serve a dockerized version of phantombot with traefik and let traefik handle the certificates for ssl.
Since phantombot uses a websocket, the websocket itself can only be accessed via wss when connecting externally but on the internal network it is listet as ws since phantombot runs in http mode.

I have tried to create an entrypoint at port 82 for wss which looks like this in the toml:

```
[entryPoints.panel]
 adress = ":82"
 [entryPoints.panel.tls]
 [[entryPoints.panel.tls.certificates]]
  certFile = "/cert.pem"
  keyFile = "/privkey.pem"
```

And the corresponding labels in the bot's docker-compose:

```
  - traefik.panel.frontend.rule=Host:my.domain.com
  - traefik.panel.frontend.entryPoints=panel
  - traefik.panel.frontend.protocol=ws
  - traefik.panel.port=82
```

Exposed ports on the container for the bot:

```
expose:
  - 80
  - 81
  - 82
```

I have tried changing the protocols, making a catchall but nothing seems to work. Everytime I try to connect, I get an error-message in the browser stating that wss://my.domain.com:82/ is not answering and a HTTP(500): Broken Pipe in the bot's interface.
I am at my wits' end.
It would be nice if someone could help me :)

Edit: docker-compose of traefik

```
version: '3'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "81:81"
      - "82:82"
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - ./traefik.log:/etc/traefik/traefik.log
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/cert.pem:/cert.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem:/privkey.pem

    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.my.domain.com
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.frontend.auth.basic.users=user:pass

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

Traefik Toml:

```
# uncomment this line to get debug info with "docker logs":
#debug = true

defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]
[traefikLog]
  filePath = "/etc/traefik/traefik.log"
  format   = "json"

# The syntax is somewhat esoteric so this is mostly copy-paste
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/cert.pem"
      keyFile = "/privkey.pem"
  [entryPoints.ytplayer]
     adress = ":81"
     [entryPoints.ytplayer.tls]
        minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
        cipherSuites = [
           "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
           "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
           "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
        ]
        sniStrict = true
        OSCPMustStaple = true
       [[entryPoints.ytplayer.tls.certificates]]
          certFile = "/cert.pem"
          keyFile = "/privkey.pem"
  [entryPoints.panel]
     adress = ":82"
     [entryPoints.panel.tls]
        minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
        cipherSuites = [
           "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
           "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
           "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
        ]
     sniStrict = true
     OSCPMustStaple = true
     [[entryPoints.panel.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/cert.pem"
      keyFile = "/privkey.pem"


[docker]
    endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    domain = "morellenoir.de"
    watch = true
    exposedbydefault = false

# enable web configuration backend.
[web]

# Web administration port, proxied in docker-compose.yml
address = ":8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#traefik configuration
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]
[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  compress = true
```

Comment: I get a different error when I edit my entrypoint the way you did above: [ERROR] [sendHTMLErrorNoHeader()@HTTPServerCommon.java:729] HTTP Server: sendHTMLError(500): Broken pipe

Comment: Are you using docker-compose for your traefik container? If so post your yml file

Comment: http redirects to https. Should I add one to redirect to the panel entrypoint?